# Control animation framerate in the object tag?

Tags: flash, frame-rate, object-tag

I have a compiled flash animation (swf) embeded into a HTML document using the object tag.

Question: There's a posibility to change the original SWF framerate using some params in the object tag?

I don't have the source code (FLA).

I want to decrease the framerate.

Thank you for any help,

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="570" height="220" id="FlashID" title="Empresas">
  <param name="movie" value="assets/flash/scroll.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="assets/flash/scroll.swf" width="570" height="220">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Este contenido requiere una nueva versión de Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible just through the object tag. That being said it may be possible to edit the SWF to get the desired result. I know [ASV](http://www.buraks.com/asv/) and some other SWF decompiling tools allow you to change the framerate of the SWF without having the FLA.